# R -ggplot - Plot p-value on figure

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph, p-value

I have a question concerning the plotting of p-values in a violin plot in using ggplot in R. I have a dataframe which contain value ordered by groups : 1000 / 2000 / 3000/ .../n

I plot a violin plot from the dataframes (see example below).

[image]

My problem is that the last value is equal to length of dataframe. In some case can be 14470 in another dataframe it can be 16043 or 13789.

I want to plot p-value (wilcoxon test) on my plot by comparing violin 2 by 2.

What I did :

```
my_comparisons_1000 <- list \
(c("1000", "2000"),c("2000", "3000"),\
c("3000", "4000"),c("4000","5000"),\
c("5000","6000"),c("6000","7000"),\
c("7000","8000"),c("8000","9000"),\
c("9000","10000"),c("10000","11000"),\
c("11000","12000"),c("12000","13000"),\
c("13000","14000"))

fig_1000<-ggplot(violin, aes(x=range_1000, y=mean_region))+
    geom_violin(scale = "width",adjust = .5,fill='#A4A4A4', color="darkred")+
    geom_boxplot(width=0.1,outlier.shape = NA) + theme_minimal()+
    scale_x_discrete(labels=c(seq(1000,length(violin[,1]),by=1000), length(violin[,1])))+
    stat_summary(fun.y=mean, geom="point",size=1,color="red",aes(shape="Mean")) +

    stat_compare_means(comparisons = my_comparisons_1000,label.y = 14)+ # Add pairwise comparisons p-value

    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))+
    guides(colour=guide_legend(order=1), shape=guide_legend(title=NULL, order=2)))
```

**Goal**

What I want is to do something shorter than my_comparisons_1000 and which fit the length of my dataframe different dataframes.

In this exemple I have groups of 1000 but I also have dataframes with groups of 500.

Actually I just have to improve 'my_comparisons_1000'

is there a way to generate several vector by step (1000) ? Something like rep or seq but I can't find it.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggpubr)
tidyiris <- iris %>% gather(key, value, -Species)
num_pairs <- length(unique(tidyiris$key)) - 1
my_comparisons <- map(seq(1, num_pairs, 1), ~c(.x, .x+1))
ggplot(tidyiris, aes(key, value)) + geom_violin() + 
  stat_compare_means(comparisons = my_comparisons)
```

[image]

For your data, it would be:

`my_comparisons <- map(seq(1000, violin$range_1000 - 1000, 1000), ~c(.x, .x + 1000))`

Comment: Thanks, it works. But the list finish at 14000 so I cannot have the last p-val from 14000 et 14470

Comment: What does `range_1000` represent? It seems odd to have one tick value that's a specific value like that. Compare to a histogram for example. The last bin ends on a round number, regardless of the highest value in the dataset.

Comment: range is a column in my dataframe. 
First 1000 hundred value have tpm_range = 1000
1000:2000 = 2000
And my length dataframe is equal to 14470 so:
value 13000:14000 = 14000
14:14470 = 15000
And then, I plot my violon plot based on tpm_range which to have several violion plot like in my exemple

How I get tmp_range :
violin$TPM_range_1000=rep(seq(1000, 15000, by=1000), each=1000, length.out=length(violin[,1]))

Comment: It's hard to follow what you're doing but like I said, something seems wrong with the x-axis.